# wikipedia table parsing, loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, for-loop

So I'm trying to create a 'deck' array filled with 'card' objects.
The 'card' object needs that atribute .front and .back.

.front needs to contain the cell of each row, aka the first column.
.back needs to contain the rest of the information of each row.

'tr' = row

'tr td' = cell

```
rowArray = []
deck = []
$('tbody').click(function(){
    var rows = $(this).find('tr');
    var cells  = $(this).find('tr td');
    for (w = 0; w<cells.length; w++){
        if (cells[w].innerText === undefined){
        }
        else{
            rowArray.push(cells[w].innerText)
        }
        };
    for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var card = {}
        var info =$(row[i]).find('td')
        var cardFront = info[0]
        card.front = $(cardFront).text()  
        for (var x=0; x< cells.length; x ++ ){
        if (cells[x].innerText === undefined){ // takes out all undefined cells
            }
        else{
            if (x % ((rows.length) / cells.length) !== 0){ // filters out the first column, so no repeat information
                card.back = cells[x].innerText; 
            }
            else{
            }
        }
     };
    deck.push(card);
    };
});
```

The problem I have is that .back for all the card objects is the last cell.

ex. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states, when I click on the table with the list of USstates, all the card.back === 'Wyoming Territory'

So the solution I'm hopping StackOverflow can help me find is: getting the information from each row, on the appropriate card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over cells (`for (var x=0; x< cells.length; x ++ )`) you're iterating over every cell in the table, the last of which is Wyoming Territory. Instead you want to be iterating over `info` which contains only cells in the given row.

```
rowArray = []
deck = []

$('tbody').click(function(){
    var rows = $(this).find('tr');
    var cells  = $(this).find('tr td');
    for (w = 0; w<cells.length; w++){
        if (cells[w].innerText === undefined){
        }
        else{
            rowArray.push(cells[w].innerText)
        }
        };
    for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var card = {}
        var info =$(rows[i]).find('td')
        var cardFront = info[0]
        card.front = $(cardFront).text()

        // Remove first cell from info
        info = info.slice(1);
        card.back = info.map(function(i,e) { return e.innerText }).toArray();

        // Move this line inside the rows loop
        deck.push(card);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new card on every row, iterate over the cells and set the card.back to the value of the cell. Of course your card always has the value of the last cell.

Solution: Try moving card = {} into your cell-loop, so that you create a new card for every cell instead of every row